# Binding to a property in a collection which returns a sub collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, observablecollection

Is there any way to bind the ListBox 'ItemsSource' to the SeriaCollection XAxeLabels or YAxeLabels?

If there is no way - i'd like to know why - and what is the workaround?

*The Binding currently specified does not seems to do that.*

```
public class AxeLabel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Brush Foreground { get; set; }
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}    

public class AxeLabels : ObservableCollection<AxeLabel>
{}

public class Seria
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Brush Color { get; set; }
    public double Thickness { get; set; }
    public PointCollection Points { get; set; }
}


public class SeriaCollection : ObservableCollection<Seria>
{
    public AxeLabels XaxeLabels { get; set; }
    public AxeLabels YaxeLabels { get; set; }
}
```

```
   <Window.Resources>
    <my:SeriaCollection x:Key="mySeria">
        <my:SeriaCollection.YaxeLabels>
            <my:AxeLabel Text="3" X="0" Y="0" Foreground="Black" />
            <my:AxeLabel Text="5" X="0" Y="-10" Foreground="Black" />
            <my:AxeLabel Text="10" X="0" Y="-20" Foreground="Black" />
            <my:AxeLabel Text="20" X="0" Y="-30" Foreground="Black" />
        </my:SeriaCollection.YaxeLabels>
        <my:SeriaCollection.XaxeLabels>
            <my:AxeLabel Text="Jan-1-2013" X="0" Y="0" Foreground="Black" />
            <my:AxeLabel Text="Jan-9-2013" X="20" Y="0" Foreground="Black" />
            <my:AxeLabel Text="Jan-18-2013" X="40" Y="0" Foreground="Black" />
            <my:AxeLabel Text="Jan-27-2013" X="60" Y="0" Foreground="Black" />
        </my:SeriaCollection.XaxeLabels>
        <my:Seria Name="FirstSeria" Thickness="2">
            <my:Seria.Points>
                <PointCollection>
                    <Point X="10" Y="10" />
                    <Point X="50" Y="50" />
                    <Point X="100" Y="30" />
                </PointCollection>
            </my:Seria.Points>
            <my:Seria.Color>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8400FF" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF5EFF00" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </my:Seria.Color>
        </my:Seria>
        <my:Seria Name="SecondSeria" Color="Blue" Thickness="6">
            <my:Seria.Points>
                <PointCollection>
                    <Point X="10" Y="60" />
                    <Point X="50" Y="30" />
                    <Point X="100" Y="20" />
                </PointCollection>
            </my:Seria.Points>
        </my:Seria>
    </my:SeriaCollection>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource mySeria}, Path=YaxeLabels}" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constructor to your `SeriaCollection` for creating the `ObservableCollection`s:

```
public class SeriaCollection : ObservableCollection<Seria>
{
    public AxeLabels XaxeLabels { get; set; }
    public AxeLabels YaxeLabels { get; set; }

    public SeriaCollection()
    {
        XaxeLabels = new AxeLabels();
        YaxeLabels = new AxeLabels();
    }
}
```

Use an `ListBox.ItemTemplate`, e.g.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource mySeria}, Path=YaxeLabels}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Width="100" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding X}" Width="50" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Y}" Width="50" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

or use the `DataType` property to assign a `DataTemplate` to your class:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:AxeLabel}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Width="100" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding X}" Width="50" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Y}" Width="50" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Both will show your content.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on your container classes, and calling OnPropertyChanged to update the binding - sorry not at my desk right now, so can't be more specific!